# pandas db created dataframe compare with csv created dataframe having type issue while comparing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a requirement to compare db migrated data to s3 created csv file for same table using python script with pandas library.

While doing this,I am facing dtype issue as data type has changed when it moves to csv file. for exmaple: table created dataframe has dtype as **object** however csv file has dtype as **float**.
and while doing **df1table.equals(df2csv)** ,getting result as **false**.

Even ,I tried to change the dtype of table data frame got error saying can't change string to float. Also facing issue with Null values of the table data frame compare to csv data frame.

I need a generic solution which work for all table and respective csv file.

Any better way to compare them. For ex: change both data frame into same type and compare.

looking for your reply.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Pandas inferring the data type, you can use `dtype=object` as parameter of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df2csv = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=object, # other params)
```

Example:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=object)

# df1
          A         B     C
0  0.988888  1.789871  12.7


# df2
                A            B     C
0  0.988887546565  1.789871131  12.7
```

CSV file:

```
A,B,C
0.988887546565,1.789871131,12.7
```

Comment: Actually,df1 is from database like below df1 = pd.read_sql(sql_quey,con = engine)..I tried you workaround but its still not match between dataframe

Comment: df1 and df2 are only here to show you the effect of `dtype=object`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I tried that dtype= object and dtype remain object but while matching data its giving false.However I manually check and they are same..Kindly assist

Comment: On a small subset of your two dataframes (10 rows, 10 columns), can you check df1 == df2?

Comment: I tried df1==df2 but its gives false for some of the fields hence datframes are not matching.both dataframe dtype is Object now

Comment: Can you try something like `df2csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=df1table.dtypes.to_dict())`?

Comment: Ok..meanwhile I tried to concat both the dataframes.Now have both the column having same name in dataframe.can we compare there data?  For example: now concatdf has following column  ID name Sal ID  name Sal...can I compare ID with ID ? Any suggestion

Comment: And this has impact to dtype or not..kindly suggest

Comment: Can you update your post with a sample of your problem?

Comment: I given dataframe data after concat.i want to compare item with item and Sal with sale..if all matches then true else false.also what is not matching and why it false

Comment: Items Sale Items Sales 
0 A 200 A 200 
1 B 410 B 410
2 NaN NaN NaT NaT

Comment: As both item and sale are matching so it should return true (data matching).also we need the generic query which work with other concat dataframe.kindly suggest